# ¿Como cambiar la variable de un objeto, contenido dentro de un ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

//Quiero aprender como se cambia la variable de un objeto que esta contenido dentro de un arraylist, por ejemplo, en este caso el array contiene 8 personas, cada uno con su nombre y apellido, y la pregunta es la siguiente: ¿Si yo solamente quiero cambiarle el apellido a esa persona sin afectar todo el objeto como se hace? y ¿Si quiero añadir una variable mas, como por ejemplo: "edad" a una de las personas, como se hace? Gracias por cualquier ayuda...

```
package prueba.array;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PruebaArray {
```

//Hago el metodo para crear el objeto y añadirlo al ArrayList

```
    public void hacerPersona(String no, String ap){                   
    personas p = new personas();
    p.setNombre(no);
    p.setApellido(ap);
    arreglo.add(p);               
}
```

// Este es el ArrayList de la clase personas, tiene los atributos: String nombre, apellidos y sus respectivos getter y setter.

```
    public static ArrayList<personas> arreglo = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
```

// Instancio el objeto y le paso los parametros al metodo hacerPersona() para que guarde varias personas

```
        personas x = new personas();
        x.hacerPersona("Raul", "Ortega");
        x.hacerPersona("Esteba", "Zuñiga");
        x.hacerPersona("Luis", "Arias");
        x.hacerPersona("Rene", "Gonzales");
        x.hacerPersona("Arnoldo", "Artavia");
        x.hacerPersona("Gilermo", "Lobos");
        x.hacerPersona("Esmeralda", "Fernandez");
        x.hacerPersona("Pedro", "Gamboa");
```

// Imprimo el contenido del ArrayList

```
        for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Persona "+i+" = "+arreglo.get(i).getNombre()+" "+arreglo.get(i).getApellido());            
    }  
}
```

Comment: Si el **ArrayList** y el método **hacerPersona()**, se encuentran en la clase PruebaArray, debes declarar el objeto x  como una instancia de esa clase **PruebaArray x=new PruebaArray();** ,acostúmbrate a nombre a tus clases iniciando con Mayúscula y a usar notación camel.

Comment: para cambiar el apellido te bastaría con recorrer el arrayList y obtener(getter) el objeto a cambiar mediante un parámetro como nombre,pero puede que uno o mas objetos tengan el mismo nombre...entonces  un atributo **id** te ayudara a identificar el objeto y modificar(setter) el apellido ;)

Comment: gracias, lo podria hacer como por ejemplo:  array.set( 6, x.setapellido("Gonzales") )?

Comment: ¿Creas un objeto `personas` para crear otro objeto `personas` con el método `hacerPersona`? ¿Qué representa `personas`? ¿Por qué en plural? ¿Cuál sería su abstracción de la realidad? ¿Qué justifica el método `hacerPersona` en lugar de usar un constructor?. Nota que se acostumbra que los nombres de clase inicien con mayúscula.

Answer (score 0):

Luego de adicionar tanto el atributo edad como sus respectivos  `setter` como `getter` en la clase `Personas`

```
private int edad;

public int getEdad() {
    return edad;
}
 
public void setEdad(int edad) {
    this.edad = edad;
}
```

en la clase **PruebaArray** realizas un par de métodos(opcionales),el cual seguirán la lógica de encontrar el objeto a modificar mediante un parámetro que coincida con algún atributo propio a modo de ejemplo usaremos el `nombre`

```
//mas detalle leer los comentarios ;)

      public void establecerEdad(int edad,String nombre){
     for(Personas p:arreglo){
        if(p.getNombre().equals(nombre)){
            p.setEdad(edad);
        }
     }
    
    }
    
    public void reestablecerApellido(String apellido,String nombre){
     for(Personas p:arreglo){
        if(p.getNombre().equals(nombre)){
            p.setApellido(apellido);
        }
     }
    }
```

ahora al imprimir los objetos del ArrayList incluyendo el getEdad() veras que las edades seran 0 salvo y excepto el objeto al cual aplicaste el método `establecerEdad()`

Answer (score -1):

Primero implementamos buenas prácticas en el código

el objeto lo creamos así:

```
public class Persona {
String nombre;
String apellido;

public Persona() {
    super();
}

// acá le agregamos un constructor con parametros
public Persona(String nombre, String apellido) {
    super();
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellido = apellido;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getApellido() {
    return apellido;
}

public void setApellido(String apellido) {
    this.apellido = apellido;
}
```

}

ya con ese cambio, lo que haces es que agregas los objetos al arreglo de la siguiente forma:

```
    arreglo.add(new Persona("Raul", "Ortega"));
    arreglo.add(new Persona("Esteba", "Zuñiga"));
    arreglo.add(new Persona("Luis", "Arias"));
    arreglo.add(new Persona("Rene", "Gonzales"));
    arreglo.add(new Persona("Arnoldo", "Artavia"));
    arreglo.add(new Persona("Arnoldo", "Artavia"));
    arreglo.add(new Persona("Esmeralda", "Fernandez"));
    arreglo.add(new Persona("Pedro", "Gamboa"));
```

ya con eso corre el ciclo para imprimir el arreglo, Saludos!

Comment: jaja Ok, gracias, pero esa no era la pregunta... sino mas bien cambiar el apellido de alguno de esos objetos ya estando dentro del array

Comment: esque bueno, quizas no lo aclare... el¡ metodo hacer persona ya me hace el objeto por si solo, pero esta en una clase aparte, crei que seria ovio....

Comment: *"Buenas prácticas"* dejando los campos sin modificador de visibilidad (deberían ser `private`) y poniendo una llamada al `super()` en una clase que no hereda de nada? De todas maneras, esta respuesta realmente no responde la duda del autor de la pregunta, que es sobre cómo modificar un atributo de un objeto dentro del array.

Comment: muchas gracias a todos, haciendo algunas cosillas logre hacerlo usando el ``` arreglo.get(6).setApellido("Gonzales"); ``` pero agradesco todos los comentarios

Comment: Ahí las disculpas, se me fue poner el private, todos los objetos heredan de la instancia Objetc de forma implícita, la llamada de super(), no está vacía, si está llamando a la clase superir Object, saludos